# Best way to implement openCV gaze tracking in a website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, tracking

I've been doing a bit of research on this for a potential project but have come up short in finding a definite answer. I've been considering how the runtime of these approaches would compare (or is there a better way to do this?). From what I've read node.js and ws have the best server side and communication performance, but I'm new to this so please tell me if this is wrong.

1) Compute entirely on client side using an openCV JS library such as (https://github.com/wallarelvo/camgaze.js). Potential downside of making the website too expensive on client end?

2) Compute logic only processing using JS <-ws-> node.js server to compute gaze coordinates and return them

3) pre-process image using openCV JS lib to extract a rectangle eye box, then send the smaller (possibly higher res) image <-ws->node.js, etc.

basically; if you had to build a web app that implemented gaze tracking, how would you do it for fastest response time?